# Rails: List Items which user has not yet Reviewed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I edit the controller code below to find items a user has yet to review?  I easily found how to find the items that a user has reviewed, but the Rails4's where.not doesn't work for it.

Code to find which items have been reviewed:

```
@items = Item.joins(:reviews).where(:reviews => { user_id: current_user.id })
```

Comment: How is where.not not working? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return items that do not have any reviews by current_user

`Item.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT id from reviews where reviews.user_id = current_user.id))`

Comment: This only checks if another user has reviewed the item. I'm looking to check if the current_user hasn't reviewed the item yet.

Comment: I've edited to better reflect your intention I believe

Comment: I get syntax errors even when I add the missing quote symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I think you need to use custom SQL statement for this. Something like the code below :

```
Item.joins(:reviews).where('NOT EXISTS(select 1 from reviews where user_id = ?)', current_user.id)
```

Comment: Is this slow and if so is there a better alternative? My guess is that I'm looking for something similar to the code Tinder uses to only show you matches you haven't reviewed.

Comment: It is not slow, it leverages the power of your database to calculate

Comment: Here's the error I get with the line you provided:PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == integer
LINE 1: ...WHERE (NOT EXISTS(select 1 from reviews where user_id == 3))

Comment: Oops my mistake, replace == by =

Comment: Is this working? `Item.joins(:reviews).where(reviews: {user_id: current_user.id }).group("reviews.id").having("count(reviews.id) = 0")`

Comment: The code below provides the error PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.  I found the error wasn't in that the .where.not statement wasn't working (it is) but instead that it's not checking if the current_user hasn't reviewed the item yet. Instead it just checks if another user has reviewed the item.

Comment: If you change group("reviews.id") to group("items.id") I think i have made a mistake there